# Current code displays a list from A2 cell, but I want the VBA code to be modified in such a way that the list starts from B2 cell?

Tags: vba, excel

The VBA code displayed below helps in capturing list of filenames in folders and sub-folders and displays that list in the excel sheet starting from A2 cell, but I want the VBA code to be modified in such a way that the list starts from B2 cell ?

```
Sub MainList()

    Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub

    xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
    Call ListFilesInFolder(xDir, True)
End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal xIsSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xSubFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long

    rowIndex = 2

    Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)

    rowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next xFile

    If xIsSubfolders Then
        For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder xSubFolder.Path, True
        Next xSubFolder
    End If

    Set xFile = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(ByVal xPath As String, ByVal xName As String)
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFolderItem As Object
    Dim xShell As Object

    xName = StrConv(xName, vbUnicode)
    xPath = StrConv(xPath, vbUnicode)

    Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set xFolder = xShell.Namespace(StrConv(xPath, vbFromUnicode))

    If Not xFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set xFolderItem = xFolder.ParseName(StrConv(xName, vbFromUnicode))
    End If

    If Not xFolderItem Is Nothing Then
        GetFileOwner = xFolder.GetDetailsOf(xFolderItem, 8)
    Else
        GetFileOwner = ""
    End If

    Set xShell = Nothing
    Set xFolder = Nothing
    Set xFolderItem = Nothing
End Function
```

Please let me know how to do the modification, so that the starting cell will be B2 instead of A2.

Comment: please indent your code at least 4 spaces so that it show up as code. ... also, your code appears to be in one column, use proper indentation throughout your code.

Comment: Hello Jsotola, please check the indented code now and let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: reformatted code to what it should look like (or something like it) ... you should see the changes once it is reviewed and hopefully accepted

Comment: one thing that leaps out ... you have a useless instruction line `rowIndex = 2` because `rowIndex` gets changed a couple of lines down .... just an observation .... it has no bearing on your question

Answer (score 0):

Change the part that says:

```
Cells(rowIndex, 1)
```

to

```
Cells(rowIndex, 2).
```

Also some **recommended** reading:

- [Referring to Ranges in VBA](http://excelmatters.com/referring-to-ranges-in-vba/)
- [Excel VBA For Complete Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.org/) (a free course)
  -